# Effective UID not taking effect on kill command

Tags: c, privileges, setuid

I'm trying to understand user ID / effective user ID. When I switch to a user (in this example apache) I still can send SIGKILL signals to programs running under root UID.

Example of output:

```
[root@devserv ~]# ./testsuid
Real UID        = 0
Effective UID   = 0
Real GID        = 0
Effective GID   = 0


Real UID        = 0
Effective UID   = 102
Real GID        = 0
Effective GID   = 501


Real UID        = 0
Effective UID   = 0
Real GID        = 0
Effective GID   = 0
```

Here the code that I'm executing:

```
[root@devserv ~]# cat test.c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/file.h>

static uid_t euid, ruid;
static gid_t egid, rgid;

void do_setuid (void) {
    int status;
    int statusgid;

    #ifdef _POSIX_SAVED_IDS
        status = setegid (egid);
        statusgid = seteuid (euid);
    #else
        status = setregid (rgid, egid);
        statusgid = setreuid (ruid, euid);
    #endif
    if (status < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Couldn't set uid.\n");
        exit (status);
    }
    if (statusgid < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Couldn't set gid.\n");
        exit (status);
    }
}


void undo_setuid (void) {
    int status;

    #ifdef _POSIX_SAVED_IDS
        status = seteuid (ruid);
        status = setegid (rgid);
    #else
        status = setreuid (euid, ruid);
        status = setregid (egid, rgid);
    #endif
    if (status < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Couldn't set uid.\n");
        exit (status);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    ruid = 0;
    euid = 102;
    rgid = 0;
    egid = 501;
    undo_setuid ();

    printf("Real UID\t= %d\n", getuid());
    printf("Effective UID\t= %d\n", geteuid());
    printf("Real GID\t= %d\n", getgid());
    printf("Effective GID\t= %d\n", getegid());

    do_setuid ();

    printf("\n\nReal UID\t= %d\n", getuid());
    printf("Effective UID\t= %d\n", geteuid());
    printf("Real GID\t= %d\n", getgid());
    printf("Effective GID\t= %d\n", getegid());

    kill(27279, SIGKILL);

    undo_setuid();

    printf("\n\nReal UID\t= %d\n", getuid());
    printf("Effective UID\t= %d\n", geteuid());
    printf("Real GID\t= %d\n", getgid());
    printf("Effective GID\t= %d\n", getegid());


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The result of the strace on my nano process:

```
[root@devserv ~]# strace -p 27279
Process 27279 attached - interrupt to quit
read(0,  <unfinished ...>
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
```

Now the question is:

How could a process with an effective UID of 102 kill a process running as root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man 2 kill` (emphasis mine):

> For a process to have permission to send a signal it must either be privileged (under Linux: have the CAP_KILL capability), or the **real** or effective **user ID of the sending process** must equal the real or saved set-user-ID of the target process.

In other words, despite having an effective UID of 102, it still has a *real* UID of 0, thus it is able to send SIGKILL to a root process.